# EF Core Foreign Key configuration problem

Tags: ef-core-2.2

i'm working on migrating actual office project to Entity Framework Core and .NET Core. 
I am stuck when i want to do Add-Migration. It seems Navigation Property and Foreign Key are not configured properly. After many trys i was not able to resolve my problem.

Error message when Add-Migration :

```
The relationship from 'PlanLang.Plan' to 'Plan.Lang' with foreign key properties {'PlanId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'GolfClubId' : int, 'PlanId' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.
```

Here are my Entities :

**GolfClub**

```
public class GolfClub
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //.. other properties, not important
}
```

**Plan**

```
public class Plan
{
    public int GolfClubId { get; set; }
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    //.. other properties, not important

    public GolfClub GolfClub { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlanLang> Lang { get; set; }
}
```

**PlanLang**

```
public class PlanLang
{
    public int GolfClubId { get;set; }
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    //.. other properties, not important

    public GolfClub GolfClub { get; set; }
    public Plan Plan { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my configurations :

```
public class GolfClubConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<GolfClub>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<GolfClub> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("gc_master");

        builder.HasKey(k => new { k.Id });
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedNever(); // to disable auto-increment

    }
}

public class PlanConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Plan>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Plan> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("gc_plan_master");

        builder.HasKey(k => new { k.GolfClubId, k.PlanId });
        builder.Property(p => p.GolfClubId).ValueGeneratedNever(); // to disable auto-increment

        builder.HasMany(p => p.Lang).WithOne(p => p.Plan).HasForeignKey(FK => FK.PlanId);
        builder.HasOne(p => p.GolfClub).WithMany().HasForeignKey(FK => FK.GolfClubId);
    }
}

public class PlanLangConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PlanLang>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PlanLang> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("gc_plan_master_lang");

        builder.HasKey(k => new { k.GolfClubId, k.PlanId, k.Lang });
        builder.Property(p => p.GolfClubId).ValueGeneratedNever(); // to disable auto-increment
        builder.Property(p => p.Lang).HasMaxLength(5);

        builder.HasOne(p => p.GolfClub).WithMany().HasForeignKey(FK => FK.GolfClubId);
    }
}
```

What I want is that Plan has 1 foreign key (GolfClubId) and PlanLang 2 foreign keys (PlanId and GolfClubId).

Which way can I proceed to do so ?

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the `GolfClubId` of the `PlanLang`. Your `Plan` have List 
of `PlanLang` and `GolfClubId` in which individual `PlanLang` have `GolfClubId` which does not make sense and that's why EF Core cannot configuring/determining the relationship.

Remove `GolfClubId` from `PlanLang` because `PlanLang` is already related to `GlofClub` through `Plan` becase `Plan` has `GolfClubId`.

Write your model classes as follows:

```
public class GolfClub
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //.. other properties, not important
}

public class Plan
{
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    public int GolfClubId { get; set; }

    //.. other properties, not important

    public GolfClub GolfClub { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlanLang> PanLangs { get; set; }
}

public class PlanLang
{
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    //.. other properties, not important

    public Plan Plan { get; set; }
}
```

And rewrite the `Plan` and `PlanLang` `EntityConfigurations` as follows:

```
public class PlanConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Plan>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Plan> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("gc_plan_master");

        builder.HasKey(k => k.PlanId);

        builder.HasMany(p => p.PlanLangs).WithOne(p => p.Plan).HasForeignKey(FK => FK.PlanId);
        builder.HasOne(p => p.GolfClub).WithMany().HasForeignKey(FK => FK.GolfClubId);
    }
}

public class PlanLangConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PlanLang>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PlanLang> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("gc_plan_master_lang");

        builder.HasKey(k => new { k.PlanId, k.Lang });

        builder.Property(p => p.Lang).HasMaxLength(5);
        builder.HasOne(p => p.Plan).WithMany().HasForeignKey(FK => FK.PlanId);
    }
}
```

Now everything should work fine!